# Css style not working on custom Wordpress theme using TailwindCSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a custom Wordpress theme using Tailwind but the styles seems to be missing, but the css file itself seems to be recognized since the theme info is recognized by Wordpress.

this is the files im working with
**functions.php**

```
<?php

function enqueue_tailwind_styles() {
    // Enqueue the style.css file from the theme root
    wp_enqueue_style('tailwind', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_tailwind_styles');

// Add other theme functions below...
remove_action( 'shutdown', 'wp_ob_end_flush_all', 1 );
```

**styles.css**

```
@import '../../theme-info.css';

@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

**theme-info.css**

```
/*
Theme Name: Car_Dealer_Groovy
Theme URI: https:/placeholder.com
Author: Santiago Mejia Wilches
Author URI: https://placeholder.com
Description: Custom theme made for a car company, name pending as of writing.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: your-text-domain
*/
```

**style.css**

```
/*
Theme Name: Car_Dealer_Groovy
Theme URI: https:/placeholder.com
Author: Santiago Mejia Wilches
Author URI: https://placeholder.com
Description: Custom theme made for a car company, name pending as of writing.
Version: 1.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: your-text-domain
*/

/*
! tailwindcss v3.3.3 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com
*/

/*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  border-width: 0; /* 2 */
  border-style: solid; /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb; /* 2 */
}


more css...
```

The wordpress information on the style.css file seems to be working but the css itself doesn't, the css code doesn't seems to be faulty because when i manually place the css in wordpress it works, this is how it looks when i put the css manually and how i normally looks
[image: how it looks when i manually input code]
[image: how it normally looks like]
I tried changing the path, adding and removing / doesn't seem to fix the issue either

Comment: Please share the contents of your `tailwind.config.js` file.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstalling Wordpress and then changing the / seems to have fixed it